# ClassNotFoundException when upgrading to AndroidX with AdMob

Tags: android, admob, classnotfoundexception, androidx, android-multidex

Recently, I upgraded to AndroidX and followed the instruction to add multidex into build.gradle. Here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hello"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 83
        versionName "83"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
}
```

gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.hello">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/ad_app_id" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I partly rolled out the new version. Many crashes happen without any root cause like this (deobfurstrated) which multidex says it is the limitation of multidex support library. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3575)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1803)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7073)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (AppComponentFactory.java:84)
  at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateReceiver (CoreComponentFactory.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3568)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300 (ActivityThread.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1803)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7073)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Comment: What devices is this error occurring on? Is it on Android 9.0? I received similar kind of error once, I might be able to help you if you tell this.

Comment: Hi, there are 2 crash groups, on from Android 4.4 to 6, another one from 7+, mostly on Heawei and Samsung devices.

Comment: Hi, you solved the problem? I have the same issue :\ @ymonaraS

Comment: @Moti No, I reverted it back to the old version and wait for any update.

Answer (score 0):

To use multidex properly you have to include three main things

1.defaultconfig multidex enabled (which you have included perfectly)

2.implementing dependency like this

```
dependencies { implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'}
```

3. include dex support in activity files in on create

```
public void onCreate(Bundle arguments)
{
MultiDex.install(getTargetContext());
super.onCreate(arguments);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it and keep updated.

Comment: Hi raj, unfortunately, the same problem still occurs on the new rollout. I might have to go back to android support. Thanks for your help.